# Is it possible to get infinite physical damage with the right cards in Paragon?

Tags: paragon

Like in other MOBAs, is there any way to get infinite damage boosts in Paragon? I know you can get infinite health with Sevarog and his ability but is there anything that allows this to be used for damage? For example:

[image]

With some hero who can gain max mana from kills, it could be infinite right?

Answer (score 1):

Sevarog has a limit to his stacks.  It was 200 before v.42, and I don't think it changed.  No other character gets stacks of any kind.  However, because of the card changes in v.42, there are technically two cards that can make you go "infinite."

The first is [Growth Totem (Growth)](http://paragon.wikia.com/wiki/Growth_Totem), which gives .8 power and 15hp for every minute you have the card equipped.

The second is [Power Tap (Knowledge)](http://paragon.wikia.com/wiki/Power_Tap), which gives 15 power permanently to your hero.  Power tap can be bought an infinite amount of times.  However, there is currently a bug with Power Tap that makes you lose the stats gained from the card when you level up.  So, currently, the card should only ever be bought after hitting level 20.

Answer (score -3):

There isn't a way to get infinite anything in any MOBA, Paragon included. Stack building features always have a cap or diminishing returns. For example, in the card in your screenshot. it increases your energy damage based on your mana by 5%, yes if you have really high mana it could be a pretty big boost, but Mana cannot be infinite (just really high).

You can get stats very high, but no infinite.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm thinking like this though http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/954437-league-of-legends/63153276